ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Docker, Python
I made a fastapi, alembic, postgres, sqlalchemy application, made a docker image, run http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs and try to create a user, but when sending a request I get the error ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
web-1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
....
web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 873, in \__connect_addr
web-1      |     tr, pr = await connector
web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 744, in     \_create_ssl_connection
web-1      |     tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
web-1      |   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 2039, in     create_connection
web-1      |   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 2016, in     uvloop.loop.Loop.create_connection
web-1      | ConnectionRefusedError: \[Errno 111\] Connection refused

docker compose and Dockerfile
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  migrate:
    build: .
    command: poetry run alembic upgrade head
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}

  web:
    build: .
    command: poetry run uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - migrate
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      ALGORITHM: ${ALGORITHM}
      ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES: ${ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}

volumes:
  postgres_data:

FROM python:3.10.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/
RUN pip install poetry && poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-dev

COPY . /app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONPATH=/app

CMD ["poetry", "run", "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

.env
# PostgreSQL
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=55555
POSTGRES_DB=test_db
DATABASE_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:55555@localhost/test_db

# JWT
SECRET_KEY=b3af51adc9749da6dfa6debec10d4854384a662a20dbf6fd1114dce53327548c
ALGORITHM=HS256
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=60

I'm recently learning Docker, I tried changing the settings of dockerfile and docker-compose, .env but I still don't understand what the problem is

DATABASE_URL's <userpass>@localhost - localhost will in this case be referring to inside your web container. You need to use the name you've assigned to your database container - so <userpass>@db/test_db.

@MatsLindh everything works now, thank you very much for your answer!
